# Neo4j Match and Merge - strange behaviour with LOAD CSV

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have a small sample dataset with 10 rows which I import from a csv file with nodes named TEvent using

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/file.csv" AS rec
CREATE (te: TEvent {l: rec.L, c: rec.C, t: rec.T, x: rec.X, us: rec.US, v: rec.V, d: rec.D, u: rec.U, h: rec.H, lc: rec.L+"_"+rec.C, lch: rec.L+"_"+rec.C+"_"+rec.H})
```

The sample file contents are

```
L,C,T,H,V,D,U,X,US

158,26823,2,2,.03,4.33,1.06,3,1

854,26843,2,2,.13,14.04,3.21,5,1.79

130,26861,2,2,.05,3.39,2.52,3,2.48

818,26863,2,2,.13,2.15,1.42,5,1.27

835,26880,2,2,.01,3.74,1.94,4,2.35

873,26902,2,2,20.27,24.65,8.69,12,4.74

187,26903,2,2,.15,.79,.5,4,.56

167,26941,2,2,0,0,0,0,0

147,26942,2,2,.36,.12,.27,2,.22

130,26982,2,2,.17,7.49,7.06,3,6.48
```

I have created a timeline index using the following Cypher statement

```
  WITH range(2014, 2020) AS years, range(1,12) as months, range(0,23) as hours
  FOREACH(year IN years |
    MERGE (y:Year {year: year})
    FOREACH(month IN months |
      CREATE (m:Month {month: month})
      MERGE (y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)
      FOREACH(day IN (CASE
                        WHEN month IN [1,3,5,7,8,10,12] THEN range(1,31)
                        WHEN month = 2 THEN
                          CASE
                            WHEN year % 4 <> 0 THEN range(1,28)
                            WHEN year % 100 <> 0 THEN range(1,29)
                            WHEN year % 400 <> 0 THEN range(1,29)
                            ELSE range(1,28)
                          END
                        ELSE range(1,30)
                      END) |     
        CREATE (d:Day {day: day})
        MERGE (m)-[:HAS_DAY]->(d)
        FOREACH(hour IN hours |
              CREATE (h:Hour {hour: hour})
              MERGE (d)-[:HAS_HOUR]->(h)))))
```

Now, I try to relate the property H from the TEvent nodes created to the hour in the timeline using

```
MATCH (te: TEvent)

MATCH (y: Year {year: 2016})-[]->(m: Month {month: 7})-[]->(d: Day {day: 4})-   []->(h:Hour {hour: te.h})

MERGE (h)<-[:AT]-(te)

RETURN h;
```

This returns (no changes, no records) consistently.

Then, I created 3 nodes using

```
        CREATE (:A {h: 2}), (:A {h:3}), (:A{h:6})
```

Now, if I try an identical attempt with only the label changed

```
MATCH (te: A)

MATCH (y: Year {year: 2016})-[]->(m: Month {month: 7})-[]->(d: Day {day: 4})-[]->(h:Hour) WHERE h.hour = te.h

MERGE (h)<-[:AT]-(te)

RETURN h;
```

This returns the expected result

```
h

"{""month"":7,""hour"":2,""year"":2016,""day"":4}"

"{""month"":7,""hour"":3,""year"":2016,""day"":4}"

"{""month"":7,""hour"":6,""year"":2016,""day"":4}"
```

I’m at a loss to understand why the first one fails and how to correct it.

Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Cheers,
Balakrishnan

Comment: You haven't shown us what properties are present on the :TEvent nodes. Also, there's a typo in the second line of the :TEvent match, you're using a variable `the`, which isn't present in the query, I think you mean to use `te`. Also, have you looked at the [GraphAware TimeTree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree)? I think that covers quite a bit of what you're doing with date/time.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thanks, I corrected the typo in my question. The properties of Event nodes are in the csv header, since I'm creating one node per row. I found the structure explained by Michael Hunger [Importing forests into Neo4J](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/04/importing-forests-into-neo4j/) and Mark Needham [Cypher-Creating a TimeTree to the day](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/) and used them to create a simple TimeTree for this evaluation. I'll look at the GraphAware TimeTree too, but the problem is not with the TimeTree itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells of the CSV are all strings by default.

You need to use `toInt(row.h)` on the data that is numeric and that you want to be numeric in your graph.

Comment: Thanks @michael-hunger , that solves the problem for me.